# Android: Image loaded from binary data in DB will not display

Tags: java, android, sql-server, image, base64

I'm developing an app in which a user can upload an image as part of a short blog post; this image is then base64 encoded and stored in a MS SQL Server database. When I try to view the image later, it doesn't display. I have a placeholder in the `ImageView` which disappears when an image is there to be loaded but no image actually displays.

Encoding image:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
img.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 35, byteArrayOutputStream);
byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
String image = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Decoding image and putting into `ImageView`:

```
byte[] decodeString = Base64.decode(blog.getImage(), Base64.DEFAULT);
Bitmap decodebitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodeString, 0, decodeString.length);
image1.setImageBitmap(decodebitmap);
```

Any help with where I'm going wrong is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `this image is then encoded to binary data ` ?? What would that be?

Comment: @greenapps It encodes to Base64

Comment: So you are calling base64 strings binary data? Pretty strange. Its more text i would say.

Comment: @greenapps As I understand it the base64 string represents the binary image data, hence my wording :)

Comment: Wrong. You should say instead `this image is then base64 encoded`.

Comment: @greenapps Fair enough

Answer (score 0):

Use this function to get `Bitmap` from base64

```
public static Bitmap decodeBase64(String input)
    {
        byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.decode(input, 0);
        return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedBytes, 0, decodedBytes.length);
    }
```

This function will set the above bitmap to `ImageView`

```
private void setImage(ImageView iv,Bitmap bitmap)
{
    iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}
```